# postgres synchronization with foreign key constraints under ubuntu

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, synchronization, postgresql-9.1

i have a local Postgres Server in 3 local branches, i need to synchronize the three to a central database i tried the database replication in the PostgreSQL Documentation it worked for a Master-Master Sync but the problem is

In my databases i have foreign keys so when syncing if a PK from the Slave database has an id that already exists in the master database it will have a new id from the sequence then all the foreign key records still have the old id

so please if  you can help me how to solve this or a good tutorial or even another solution to do so

thanks in advance

Comment: The question isn't very clear...

Comment: For me, the easiest way is use Guids as IDs, implementing diferent will be a little more paintful.

Comment: sorry i'm still very beginner in Postgres what are Guids IDs

Comment: For Denis let me explain what i mean when a record is synced from the slave database it will have another ID so in the other tables where there are foreign relations to that ID will remain as is so let's say 

if i have an employee with id=10 he works in a project so in the project record i have emp_id=10 (FK) when the employee record is synced it will become id=15 but the emp_id in the project table will stay 10 which links to another employee 

i hope i well managed to explain this issue i don't know if there is a technical name for that case 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got easy way to add foreign key constrains simply make txt file of foreign key sql commands and give ';' after each sql command and use below code it works perfectly...

```
private void FunAddForeignKeys()
    {
        SqlConnection clientConn = new SqlConnection(lconString);
                    if (clientConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        clientConn.Open();
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand Command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(GetSql("ForeignKeyQueries.txt"), clientConn);

        try
        {
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Foreign keys added");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Closing the connection should be done in a Finally block
            clientConn.Close();
        }
}
        private string GetSql(string Name)
        {
         try
        {
            // Gets the current assembly.
            Assembly Asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            // Resources are named using a fully qualified name.
            Stream strm = Asm.GetManifestResourceStream(Asm.GetName().Name + "." + Name);

            // Reads the contents of the embedded file.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strm);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("In GetSQL: " + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my databases i have foreign keys so when syncing if a PK from the Slave database has an id that already exists in the master database it will have a new id from the sequence then all the foreign key records still have the old id

Make the original branch a part of your primary key.  Then you can ensure that everything is tracked through consistently.  This is an area where multi-column primary keys really shine.